# EasyAdmin 4 and Symfony 6 : AssociationField doesn't allow me to filter results

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

for days I've been trying to retrieve in EasyAdmin only the formateurFormations whose 'masque' field is set to true.

So i wrote :

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        yield IdField::new('id');
        yield AssociationField::new('formateurFormations')->setQueryBuilder(function ($queryBuilder) {
            return $queryBuilder->andWhere('masque = true'); // your query

        });
    }
```

Here is my relation :

```
#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'formation', targetEntity: FormateurFormation::class, orphanRemoval: true)]
private Collection $formateurFormations;
```

I've tried a lot of things following [EasyADmin official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.x/EasyAdminBundle/fields/AssociationField.html) but it's like setQueryBuilder is purely ignored.

Hope that someone will help me on that :/

Comment: Did you check in Web profiler > Doctrine tab that the query is executed with conditions added in the query builder?

Comment: No, i used formatValue() instead of setQueryBuilder()

Comment: Could you check the profiler with setQueryBuilder()?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue in the GitHub repository of Easyadmin because `AssociationField::setQueryBuilder()` doesn't behave as documented: https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/5081

In the comments, you can find some examples of working code to make the `setQueryBuilder()` method work.

In your case, there might be some missing code regarding how your entity and its repository are configured, but I would try something like this:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    $repo = $this->yourEntityRepository; // import the Entity Repository and initialize in your __constructor()
    $masqued = $repo->findWithMasque(); // Create a method in your Entity Repository that returns what you need

    return [
        IdField::new('id'),
        AssociationField::new('formateurFormations')
                        ->setQueryBuilder(
                            fn (QueryBuilder $queryBuilder) => $queryBuilder
                                ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->in('entity.id', ':masqued'))
                                ->setParameter('masqued', $masqued)
                        ),
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thx. I use formatValue() tu do the job and it works well :)